# Automatic character replacement excel

Tags: excel, replace, character

I've checked various examples on various sites and I'm unable to find a way to automatically replace a character (.) when entering it in a cell in Excel 2013.

What I want is to be able to replace a "." with nothing or rather remove the dot. It would be a part of numbers, something like 33.33.2320 and should be edited to 33332320. Retaining trailing zero as well or any leading zeros.

This I would like to do on an entire column if possible in Excel.
The dot could be either manually entered or copy/pasted and need to be removed automatically upon doing so.

I've tried with Macros, substitute etc, but that seems to be an action taken AFTER not at "runtime" if you know what I mean.

Data validation actually stops from value being entered and this is not what I want. If someone enters dot either manually or copy/pasted it simply should be removed.

Thanks

Comment: It is called Find/Replace... this isn't really a programming question...

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a macro which runs if the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) occurs.

While in Excel, right click on the Worksheet name tab of the worksheet you want listening the event and choose `View Code`. Now you are not in an general module but in a worksheet class module.

Therein put that code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Column = 3 Then 'only column 3 = C

  For Each oCell In Target

   If InStr(oCell.Text, ".") <> 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'We change workshheet cells within Worksheet_Change.
                                     'So we must disable events to prevent endless loop.
    oCell.NumberFormat = "@"
    oCell.Value = Replace(oCell.Value, ".", "")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If

  Next

 End If

End Sub
```

Now every time if something changes in this worksheet, then the code runs. If the change is in column `C` and the cell contains ".", then the replacement is done.

To retain leading zeros, the cell mus set to `Text` number format.

Note the `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`. If we change worksheet cells within Worksheet_Change, we must disable events to prevent endless loop. Also we must activate events later because if not, no event procedures will run from this time on.

---

There is one problem with this. If you input  `001.234`, then the leading zeros will be lost. This is because the change event starts **after** input and then the number is `1.234` already. There is no way around this in my opinion.  `001.234.567` will work since this is **not** assumed as number but as string.

---

If possible, you could set the whole column in `Text` number format. This will solve the problem. But then number input is no more possible in this column.

Comment: Did you check to ensure that this keeps leading/trailing zeros. You may have to wrap `Replace ...` in `Cstr`

Comment: `Replace` will return a string already. If the need is **not** to get a number - which will never have leading zeros - then we need having number format `Text`.

Comment: This I have already mentioned. It is the same problem as with `001.234`. You should set the whole column in Text number format. This will solve the problem. This also is already mentioned.

Comment: The EnableEvents would be best used once outside the loop.

Comment: Axel, thank you very much!! That was perfect. I used the code you gave and during compile I was getting an error with wrong number of arguments for the Replace function, then looked up on it and looks like for internal functions I need to use: "VBA.Strings.Replace" which compiled successfully and now I can enter numbers with leading/trailing  zeros and all numbers are retained without the decimals.

Comment: If you had to use the fully qualified function name `VBA.Strings.Replace` then maybe some add-in has overwritten the `Replace` function using the same name. That would be bad practice from that add-in.

Comment: I'm not sure Axel, don't know much about Excel/VB programming. But thanks anyway, it is working as expected.